# How to enable USB Serial on multiple activities in android application?

Tags: android, android-activity, usbserial

I want to make an app that can transfer data to a USB-connected device. The app has multiple activities (and multiple layouts). How can I make it so that I only need to enable USB connection in one activity, then when you go to the next activity you can still transfer data without having to re-enable the USB connection?

I'm using this tutorial as a reference : https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/communicate-with-your-arduino-through-android/

I also use USB Serial Library (as used in the tutorial above) by Github user felHR85. Link : https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/

Appreciate the help! Thanks!